# Status Bar Not Hiding

Tags: xcode, statusbar

I am having this trouble hiding the status bar. It is still showing up in the simulator and on the iphone.

I made sure in my .plist files that

```
"Status Bar Is Initially Hidden : YES"
"View controller-based status bar appearance : NO"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plist value is only specifying to hide the status bar when launching – in your application delegate, you need to set the status bar to hidden:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: You can also do some cool things using the similar 
setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation: method. You can use a Fade or Slide animation to hide/show the status bar.